# Can Excel vba invoke an autofilter when a hyperlink is clicked to open new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, autofilter

Fairly new to programming and I want to know if it's possible to create an autofilter on a workbook that is opened by a hyperlink on a separate workbook. I'll explain: I have code to compile a summary of information on one spreadsheet, `workbook1`. The information resides in `workbook2`. The user is working in `workbook1` and inputs the record numbers they are searching. When the macro runs all the associated information from each record number gets imported from `workbook2` into `workbook1`. I currently create a hyperlink to open `workbook2` (in case user needs further details) and I would like to have `workbook2` open up with an autofilter based on the record numbers when the hyperlink is clicked. Is this possible? I've read and seen code where the autofilter is invoked through a hyperlink from sheet to sheet in the same workbook, but not sure I comprehend vba code enough to apply it on separate workbooks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set workbook 2 as a variable in your workbook 1 code module, then call your methods.

```
dim wb as workbook
dim i as integer
set wb = workbooks.open("C:\dogstuff\sticks\thebeststicks.xlsx")
i = thisworkbook.worksheets("throwingstuff").cells(5,5).value
wb.worksheets("rank").range(cells(2,1),cells(2,10)).autofilter
wb.worksheets("rank").range(cells(2,1),cells(2,10)).autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=I
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works when added to module, however, it is not exactly how I want it to work. What I need is to create the hypelink, say **A1** in **workbook1**, which I already have a module for. Then when the user clicks on that hyperlink. The second spreadsheet opens and the autofilter gets applied. I'll post what I have so far in a seperate comment. I get a runtime error 1004 with the following code....

Comment: On 'Sheet1' of **workbook1** I have:  `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)  
Dim i As String  
With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\oolmos\Desktop\Ultimate Data.xls")

i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
Workbooks("UltimateData.xls").Worksheets("Cranks&BB").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 33)).AutoFilter  
Workbooks("UlmtiateData.xls").Worksheets("Cranks&BB").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 33)).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=i  
End With  
 
End Sub`

Comment: I was about to reply here, but I just saw your other answer below. I'm glad I could help! Since my answer was helpful, if you could mark it as the accepted answer, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JMcD, your post helped me figure things out. I used your code, modified it to fit my needs, and inserted in module2. I use another module to create hyperlink. I then put a _followhyperlink private sub in workbook1's sheet1 that calls module2. Now if I click the hyperlink, workbook2 opens up, applies the autofilter based on the value in A1. I will post the code here once I figure out how to make it look pretty as your post above. Thanks again.